# How to run CodeIgniter inside OpenCart?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I have a website www.example.com in OpenCart, I want to install CodeIgniter in the subfolder like www.example.com/codeigniter/, I am able to run core-php in the subfolder but confuse to run CodeIgniter.
Please Help me out

Comment: CI is package that you have to paste in root folder of XAMP , MAMP ,WAMP that is what you have to do. If you want in subfolder of your project you hav to paste in root directory

Comment: I have already done it. but the problem is , lets take an example

Suppose my website name is www.abc.com in opencart, and subfolder name is "ci" i.e. www.abc.com/ci/ where i have to install codeigniter. 

and in codeigniter there is controller name let say ci_controller , now the problem is that 
whenever I go to the link www.abc.com/ci/index.php/ci_controller .. it shows 404 error . So I just confuse, please help me out